# Import layer from file with url to photo

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've created my own map using Google Maps. I've added layer from CSV file, selected lat and long. Everything works fine. Now for each marker I can add a photo from url. When map is exported to KML file the url address is saved, as you can see:

```
<Data name='x'>
    <value>23.14456</value>
</Data>
<Data name='y'>
    <value>53.12582</value>
</Data>
<Data name='gx_media_links'>
    <value>http://www.bbn.gov.pl/dokumenty/zalaczniki/1/1-17018.jpg</value>
</Data>
```

and when file is imported again photos are there. But my question is how to import them from CSV file in the first place?
I've tried adding a column `gx_media_links` to my CSV file but it didn't worked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it can't be done by CSV file directly, but I've found some workaround:

1. Change column's with links name to **exactly** `gx_media_links` and save as CSV file.
2. Import the CSV into a new layer.
3. Download the layer as a KMZ file (via the main menu button)
4. Import the KMZ file back into a new layer.
5. This new layer should now have visible images, but the KMZ export/import has a side effect, ends up duplicating the data into the description. So open the Data table for the new layer, and delete the Description column

Comment: Hi, I have done it, but I get only black boxes instead of the actual images...am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

export as a KML,
edit a "description" for each point as html image:

```
<description><![CDATA[<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" height="200" width="auto" >]]></description>
```